# Need to find equation for moving towards something on a grid

Tags: javascript, tracking

Ok, I wrote a script that let's you move around and what not on a grid made up of a bunch of put together 'x' letters. So you know what it looks like, here is the JS that makes it:

```
function generate_page() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var lines = 20;
    var output;
    while (x <= lines) {
        while( y <= lines*2){
            if (x == 0 && y == 1) {
                output = "<span id='x" + x + "_" + y + "' style='background-color: red'>o</span>";
            } else if (x == 3 && y == 5) {
                output = "<span id='x" + x + "_" + y + "' style='background-color: green'>z</span>";
            } else {
                output = ("<span id='x" + x + "_" + y + "'>x</span>");
            }
            $('#board').append(output);
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
        x++;
        $('#board').append('<br />');
    }
}
```

Now, I have a green character on the board that I'm trying to program to go towards the red one that you control. I have the North, South, East, and West functions worked out. However, for the life of me, I can *not* figure out the little algorithm to make one go towards the other.I have tried with the following, but it doesn't work what-so-ever. Could anyone help me come up with a way for one character to track another? Here is my failed attempt:

```
function moveGreen() {
    var x_distance = currentX_green - currentX_red;
    var y_distance = currentY_green - currentY_red;
    var larger;
    if (x_distance > y_distance) {
        larger = 'x';
    } else if (y_distance > x_distance) {
        larger = 'y';
    } else {
        larger = 'o';
    }
    if (larger == 'x') {
        if (x_distance > 0){
            north('green');
        } else {
            south('green');
        }
    } else if (larger == 'y'){
        if (y_distance > 0) {
            west('green');
        } else {
            east('green');
        }
    } else if (larger == 'o'){
        if (y_distance > 0){
            east();
        } else if (y_distance == 0) {
            if (x_distance > 0) {
                north();
            } else {
                south();
            }
        } else {
            west();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: [Here](http://jackscode.99k.org/nav_large.html) is the current program. Ignore the green moves on red stuff.

Edit 2: Ok, I updated the problems with the west and stuff without green. Here is the new code:

```
function moveGreen() {
    var x_distance = currentX_green - currentX_red;
    var y_distance = currentY_green - currentY_red;
    var larger;
    if (Math.abs(x_distance) > Math.abs(y_distance)) {
        larger = 'x';
    } else if (Math.abs(y_distance) > Math.abs(x_distance)) {
        larger = 'y';
    } else {
        larger = 'o';
    }
    if (larger == 'x') {
        if (x_distance > 0){
            north('green');
        } else {
            south('green');
        }
    } else if (larger == 'y'){
        if (y_distance > 0) {
            west('green');
        } else {
            east('green');
        }
    } else if (larger == 'o'){
        if (y_distance > 0){
            east('green');
        } else if (y_distance == 0) {
            if (x_distance > 0) {
                north('green');
            } else if (x_distance < 0){
                south('green');
            }
        } else {
            west('green');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more information then "doesn't work what-so-ever". Does it just stay still? Do random circles? Pop up an error message box?

Comment: Well, it just seems to move randomly, I'll put up a link to the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one obvious issue is that you need to check the absolute values near the top.

instead of

```
if (x_distance > y_distance) {
    larger = 'x';
} else if (y_distance > x_distance) {
```

you need

```
if (Math.abs(x_distance) > Math.abs(y_distance)) {
    larger = 'x';
} else if (Math.abs(y_distance) > Math.abs(x_distance)) {
```

since you still want the "biggest" even if it's negative.

*update* now it stops where x=y.  looking at the code there's no "green" in the argument to east etc for that case.

*update* well, now it goes wrong when it's on a diagonal so i would guess east/west are the wrong way round for the "o" case (and indeed, they are not consistent with the "y" case).  looks a lot nicer now!

Comment: Thank you so much! I did this earlier but forgot to re instate it after some tweaking. Really appreciated. :D

Comment: was that it?  i thought there must be more... glad i could help!

Comment: Haha, yea. Now I'm trying to get the bot to move also according to the way you can rap. I think I'll be able to get it.

Comment: Alright, now that I inspect closer, this still isn't working. :/ Sorry for misconception. any farther ideas?

Comment: OK, what I fixed that, now what? Also, the link I provided is always the latest code.

Comment: Ok, I switched y movements for the o part, and I think it works now. :D Uploading the new code, I'll test it some more.